# Express gateway gives 404

Tags: node.js, express-gateway

I'm the service url as
GET REQUEST `http://myipaddress:5000/api/Tenant/tenants/{TenantID}`

The `TenantID`  will be dynamic

I also have the POST as  `http://myipaddress:5000/api/Tenant/tenants`

In this post request payload is passed in request body.

My gateway config yml file is as below

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/ip'
  tenant-api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/api/Tenant/tenants/*'

serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  tenant-svc:
    url: 'http://localhost:5000'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
      - tenant-api
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
              changeOrigin: true
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: tenant-svc 
              changeOrigin: true
```

I get 404 when i try to perform the GET Request via proxy. Also can you let me know how can i add the POST api endpoints in my gatewayconfig.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you have multiple actions in proxy policy

```
- action:  # this one is always executing and goes to the httpbin
      serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
      changeOrigin: true
- action:
      serviceEndpoint: tenant-svc 
      changeOrigin: true
```

remove the first action to make all calls go to tenant-svc

```
- action:
      serviceEndpoint: tenant-svc 
      changeOrigin: true
```

This configuration will accept all methods GET,POST whatever  on '/api/Tenant/tenants/*' urls

to make Express-Gateway process  /api/Tenant/tenants url you can modify api endpoint like:

```
paths: ['/api/Tenant/tenants/*', '/api/Tenant/tenants' ]
```

https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/configuration/gateway.config.yml/apiEndpoints#markdown

I would assume no special handling of GET POST is required. 
In case  you need Gateway to filter only specific methods you can add

```
methods: 'POST,PUT'
```

to your api Endpoint configuration

So final config can look like

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  tenant-api:
    host: localhost
    methods: 'GET,POST,PUT' 
    paths: ['/api/Tenant/tenants/*', '/api/Tenant/tenants' ] 

serviceEndpoints:
  tenant-svc:
    url: 'http://localhost:5000'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - tenant-api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: tenant-svc 
              changeOrigin: true
```

Or you can have multiple API Endpoints to the same pipeline with methods

```
  tenant-api-1:
    host: localhost
    methods: 'GET' 
    paths: '/api/Tenant/tenants/*'

  tenant-api-2:
    host: localhost
    methods: 'POST' 
    paths:  '/api/Tenant/tenants'
```

**Update: Multi service usage**

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  hostname: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  tenant-api:
    host: localhost
    methods: 'GET,POST,PUT' 
    paths: ['/api/Tenant/tenants/*', '/api/Tenant/tenants' ] 
  product-api:
    host: localhost
    paths: ['/api/products/*'] 
serviceEndpoints:
  tenant-svc:
    url: 'http://localhost:5000'
  product-svc:
    url: 'http://localhost:6000'
policies:
  - proxy
pipelines:
  tenant:
    apiEndpoints:
      - tenant-api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: tenant-svc 
              changeOrigin: true
  products:
    apiEndpoints:
      - product-api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: product-svc 
              changeOrigin: true
```

Comment: So does it mean that I can only specify only one action. I want to use this solution for my microservices application. I've have more than 70 microservice , where each service is having atleast 3 endpoints. How can i have single config to accommodate all the services ?

Comment: typically you create multiple pipelines for different 
and different api endpoints to match urls 


/tenants/* -> goes to "tenants" pipeline -> the pipeline has proxy policy to tenant-src endpoint

 /products/* -> goes to "products" pipeline -> the pipeline has proxy policy to products-src endpoint

---- 
multiple actions are possible. for example if you have condition so action will be executed only if condition is matched 

for the most use cases  you need just one action

Comment: I've updated the answer with example.
Btw, when you want to see where exactly request is proxied run Express Gateway with env variable "LOG_LEVEL=debug"

for example "LOG_LEVEL=debug npm start" 
it will output messages with target url if proxy policy is triggered

Comment: Great that really helped me. Thanks

Comment: so to route resource URLs to appropriate microservice I must declare an apiEndpoint, a serviceEndpoint and a pipeline with a proxy policy for each one?